# Place button text aligned with textview content

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I have a fragment with several textviews displaying the user's information. I wanted to place the button to change password like an hyperlink. Here you can see the button's text (Cambiar contraseña >) is not aligned with the text of the textviews above it

[image]

I have a Scrollview containing a Linearlayout where I have all the textviews.

Comment: Could you please post your layout code?

Answer (score 0):

Buttons have padding. You could use negative margin for the button, but the press highlight will be off. You could therefore use a TextView instead, and set the background to ?attr/selectableItemBackground.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Spannables for hyperlink like appearance. They can also be programmed to react on clicks and URIs and align nicely within paragraph.